# How to update react ref if child elements of ref.current change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React refs to handle click outside of an element.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

export const useClickOutside = (ref, callback = () => {}) => {
  const handleClick = e => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
      callback();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', handleClick);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleClick);
    };
  }, []);
};
```

The problem is that sometimes `ref.current.contains(e.target)` returns false while e.target is an actual child element of ref.current.

I think this happens because the child elements of ref.current change and ref.current is not correctly updated.

I've made a small gif of the problem : [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/ii3JffV.gifv)

Comment: I'd rather guess, the problem is that `ref.current` returns either DOM element or corresponding component, thus applying `contains()` method to query for children nodes (if that was your intention) is meaningless.

Besides, calling `handleClick()` outside of `useClickOutside()` should cause an error.

Defining `useEffect()` within `useClickOutside()` instead of main component definition body is also looks not proper to me.

Would you describe your use case in a bit more details so that alternative solutions of your problem may be suggested?

Comment: You can debug it inside the `handleClick` function. Just `console.log` ref.current and e.target to check these variables to correct values.

Comment: I've added a gif so you can understand

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit late and also not the ideal solution but I had the same problem and just solved it by checking if the click was inside react-select ie. checking if the event.target.id included "react-select":

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    if (ref.current && !ref.current.contains(e.target)) {
        if (!e?.target?.id.includes('react-select')) {
            callback()
        }
    }
}
```